# Bounty award hover state causes page shifting

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Not really a big issue.

The rounding of the bounty award on and off state are different. This causes the page to shift when you hover over the bounty button, see animation.

[image]

This isn't really a large issue, but generally you don't want page items shifting merely due to a hover state on a link.

Comment: Same bug as [this report on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230370/the-entire-answer-is-moving-when-hovering-the-bounty-button).

Comment: Off topic, I love your screenshots!! How do you create them?

Comment: @ckpepper02 http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/790/how-to-embed-screen-capture-videos-as-animated-gifs-in-answers

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed with the April 2015 [updates to the site](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/8708).