# Questions with accepted answers on the 'All Questions' pages don't have a highlighted background to differentiate from unaccepted answers

Tags: bug, design

As far as I know this is only an issue on this site and not any other network sites. You can see from the image below, that in the question list on the 'Questions' pages, questions with accepted answers don't have the background color highlight that they should(?) have. They do however on the front page.

[image]
[image]

If you inspect the CSS, the style for the background highlight is there but is being overridden.

[image]

Is this an oversight? Could we fix it?

**Edit:** I just found this question: [Updates to the site](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/updates-to-the-site) should I post this here?

Comment: Sharp! Yes, it'd be great if you could post this as an answers to the [Updates to the site](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/updates-to-the-site\) question. That way, Stéphane Martin, the designer will see it. Thanks!

Comment: I always thought this was an intentional thing - it's overridden for a reason