# The accepted answer and not accepted answer blips have quite similar color

Tags: bug, design, site-redesign

The accepted answer blip and the not accepted answer blip (vote accepted on and vote accepted off) have quite the same color. To many who are not visually accurate very much like myself, it becomes really confusing. In this question, I misclicked on the accepted answer to unaccept it thinking I didn't accept it just to know that I had.

It's RGB 94, 196, 175 (`#5ec4af`) vs. 192, 192, 192 (`#c0c0c0`).

[image: Vote accepted on and vote accepted off colors can be confusing.]

---

To clarify for those not getting it here's a demo of how the screenshot above looks for people with Color Blindness:

[image]

So while you may see the original image as two distinct things anyone with color blindness would see the exact same for an Accepted Answer and Unaccepted Answer.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem

Comment: does that cause an issue with color blind people?

Comment: Like I said in https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3157/3962 -- I'm slightly color blind as far as blue/purple goes, however I seem to be unable to distinguish between these subtle greys.

Comment: @Luciano yes I just updated to show this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I personally don't experience this, but I seem to have pretty good colour vision. I can imagine that with less-optimal colour vision, the difference may be insufficient. Not everyone's cones are as good as mine.

An option to improve this would be to make the icon that is now grey a negative: grey outline, grey checkmark, white fill.

[image]

Comment: I feel like we could slightly change this and migrate it to the main Q&A.

Comment: This will be good, it's like you fill the button once you accept it.

Comment: who do we ping to get this done?

Comment: @PieBie just added the Bug tag and will reach out to the Gods

Comment: neat trick, I'll have to remember that one :)